# ¿por que me da este error Undefined variable:?

Tags: php

Disculpen soy nuevo en PHP y solo estoy haciendo pruebas por lo tanto no se porque se genera este error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: firstName in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Programación\PHP\prueba.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined property: person::$ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Programación\PHP\prueba.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: lastName in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Programación\PHP\prueba.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined property: person::$ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Programación\PHP\prueba.php on line 8

```
<?php

class person{
    var $firstName=null;
    var $lastName=null;

    function fullname(){
            return $this->$firstName . ' ' . $this->$lastName;
    }
}

$person1 = new person;
$person1->firstName = 'Samuel';
$person1->lastName = 'Vieyra';


exit($person1->fullname());
?>
```

**Update1**

```
<?php

class person{
    var $firstName=null;
    var $lastName=null;

    function fullname(){
            return $this->$firstName . ' ' . $this->$lastName;
    }
}

$person1 = new person();
$person1->firstName = 'Samuel';
$person1->lastName = 'Vieyra';


exit($person1->fullname());
?>
```

Comment: Amigo en la linea 8 ($person1 = new person), deberias colocar los parentesis para señalar el contructor del objeto. 
$person1 = new person();

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigue dándome el mismo error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es un error de sintaxis, se debe al **$** que hace referencia a la propiedad dentro de la línea `return $this->$firstName . ' ' . $this->$lastName;`

Lo correcto, sería

```
return $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName;
```

Código completo:

```
class person{
    var $firstName=null;
    var $lastName=null;

    function fullname(){
            return $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName;
    }
}

$person1 = new person;
$person1->firstName = 'Samuel';
$person1->lastName = 'Vieyra';


exit($person1->fullname());
```

Te recomiendo leer la [documentación de orientación a objetos de php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php) que es muy completa, y te va a ayudar mucho!

Saludos y éxitos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, y también por la recomendación